# Node.js error: Cannot find module './decimal128'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, npm

I have a simple REST API deployed in Heroku.  It uses MongoDB as the document storage service for the endpoints. It fails to run properly ever since I ran `npm install` to add another module for a different set of features. It doesn't matter what I do at that point, until I replace the `node_modules` folder (locally) with an older version before the last time I ran `npm install`, and re-deploy.

```
2018-08-03T16:12:14.920647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command npm start
2018-08-03T16:12:18.405746+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-03T16:12:18.405762+00:00 app[web.1]: > todolistapi@1.0.0 start /app
2018-08-03T16:12:18.405764+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-08-03T16:12:18.405766+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-03T16:12:18.593093+00:00 app[web.1]: /app
2018-08-03T16:12:18.594629+00:00 app[web.1]: /app
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115500+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:549
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115542+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115544+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115545+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115547+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './decimal128'
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115550+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115551+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115553+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115554+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115556+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js:6:22)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115558+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115559+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115561+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115562+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2018-08-03T16:12:19.115564+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I read at least 10 other articles, and tried downgrading, reinstalling MongoDB with no success.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It might help the community to assist you if you were to edit the question to identify the module you installed that broke things. Thanks.

Comment: MandyShaw, thank you.  It isn't the module, per se, that broke things, it is running the command NPM install, which seems to overwrite the version of MongoDB I have locally.  After doing more research I suspect the real problem might be more likely that my push to Heroku includes by node_modules folder.  I just ran these commands and it's working now:
    git rm -r --cached node_modules
    git commit -m 'Remove the now ignored directory node_modules'
    git push origin master

Answer (score 1):

Issue: my local node_modules folders was being included in my push to Heroku.  Once removed, the application runs fine on Heroku:

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m 'Remove the now ignored directory node_modules'
git push origin master
```

Comment: Remember to mark your self-answer as correct since it solved the problem for you